# calculating a moving average and add it to an array

Tags: php

I have a `mysql` query result. When I loop through the results I'm creating an array out if it like this:

```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    array_push($resultsArray, [
      'hours_open'   => $row['hours_open'],
      'hours_closed' => $row['hours_closed']
      'ma_hours_closed' => 'what to put here..'
    ]);
  }
```

What I would like is a moving average, based on the hours_open with a period of 6 (so the 7th record should give me the average of records 1 to 6, the 8th record the average of records 2 to 7, and so on.

Any thoughts on this?

**EDIT**

```
$data = $r['Data'];
$results = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

    if ($i < 5) {
        $ma_hours_closed = 0;
    } else {
        $sum = 0;
        for ($c = $i-6; $c < $i; $c++) {
            $sum += $results[$c]['hours_closed'] / 6;
        }
        $ma_hours_closed = $sum;
    }

    array_push($results, [
      'hours_open' => $data[$i]['hours_open'],
      'hours_open' => $data[$i]['hours_closed'],
      'ma_hours_closed' => $ma_hours_closed
    ]);
}
```

It gives me a valid output and it seems to be correct. Is this a right way to go with it?

Comment: Yes, but you're supposed to do the thinking first, experiment then show us so we can tell you what you're doing wrong (hint: array_push(), count(), array_shift())

Comment: @symcbean I edited my post. Can you comment? Many thanks!

Comment: What you've named as sum is actually the mean, and the point of moving average is that not all the historic values are in scope. YOU NEED TO EXCLUDE OLD VALUES from the list you are adding up to get the average

Comment: @symcbean thats right, but I believe I'm not taking all the historic data into account since I'm starting the loop in the loop at `$i-6`. I checked it with excel and it gives me the same results.